# Correcting for multiple comparisons when testing proportions adding up to 1

Tags: anova, degrees-of-freedom

I'd like to test differences between groups in how much relative time they spent in a particular location.

Example:

**Group A**
John in room 1: 20 %
John in room 2: 70 %
John in room 3: 10 %
Jerry in room 1: 30 %
Jerry in room 2: 70 %
Jerry in room 3: 0 %

**Group B**
Lisa in room 1: 40 %
...

As you see, the proprtions always add up to 100 %. Now I want to know if eg. group A spent more/less time in room 1 than group B. For every room I conduct an ANOVA (because each group was tested twice, but let's leave that out for simplicity) and then I'd like to correct for multiple comparisons (ie., for testing 3 rooms).

I don't like to correct by 3 though, since I'm not testing 3 independent measures. If I know your relative time spent in room 1 and 2, your time in room 3 is already determined. I'd like to correct for the actual degrees of freedom or number of independent tests. How do I calculate them? Is it just 3-1 = 2 ?

Comment: This could be a homework problem...

Comment: Every question could turn out to be a homework question. However, in this case it is a research question. I'm neuroscience doctoral student, the rooms are actually mental states of human subjects as indicated by specific features in the EEG. I wanted to keep the question simple though...
The problem occurs frequently in my field and different research groups tend to do the analysis in different ways. I'd like to find an optimal solution and present it to my colleagues in order to make our results more comparable in the long term.